# Tengo un error en mi código con php al registrar

Tags: php, mysql, html5, base-de-datos

Bueno estaba haciendo un ejercicio el cual era hacer un formulario para registrar desde la pagina hacia una base de datos mysql.

Este es el codigo de la página.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Registrar Articulos</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <form name="frm" action="php/registrararticulos.php" method="post">
        <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Descripcion</th>
            <td><input type="text" name="desc"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th>Marca</th>
                <td><input type="text" name="marca"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th>Precio de compra</th>
                <td><input type="number" name="precom"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th>Precio de venta</th>
                <td><input type="number" name="preven"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th>Cantidad</th>
                <td><input type="number" name="cant"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th>Peso</th>
                <td><input type="text" name="peso"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th>Tipo de articulo</th>
                <td>
                <select name="tipo">
                    <option value="Perecible">Perecible</option>
                    <option value="No perecible">No perecible</option>
                    <option value="Conserva">Conserva</option>
                    <option value="Limpieza">Limpieza</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th>Fecha de vencimiento</th>
                <td><input type="date" name="fecven"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th>Fecha de compra</th>
                <td><input type="date" name="feccom"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th>Codigo de barra</th>
                <td><input type="number" name="codbarra"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th>Proveedor</th>
                <td>
                <select name="proveedor">
                    <option value="P&G">P&amp;G</option>
                    <option value="Alicorp">Alicorp</option>
                    <option value="Gloria">Gloria</option>
                    <option value="PEPSICO">PEPSICO</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Y este el que usé para realizar la conexión.

```html
<?php
$conexion = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("bdabarrotes",$conexion);
?>
```

Y el código que enviaba los datos a la database.

```html
<?php
include('conexion.php');
$desc=$_POST['desc'];
$marca=$_POST['marca'];
$precom=$_POST['precom'];
$preven=$_POST['preven'];
$cant=$_POST['cant'];
$peso=$_POST['peso'];
$tipo=$_POST['tipo'];
$fecven=$_POST['fecven'];
$feccom=$_POST['feccom'];
$codbarra=$_POST['codbarra'];
$proveedor=$_POST['proveedor'];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO articulos(
    desc,
    marca,
    precom,
    preven,
    cant,
    peso,
    tipo,
    fecven,
    feccom,
    codbarra,
    proveedor
)VALUES(
    '$desc',
    '$marca',
    '$precom',
    '$preven',
    '$cant',
    '$peso',
    '$tipo',
    '$fecven',
    '$feccom',
    '$codbarra',
    '$proveedor'
)")or die("ERROR");
mysql_close($conexion);
header('location:../webregistrararticulos.php');
?>
```

Siempre me da el error, los datos si se envian a la pagina pero no a la base de datos.
Ayuda.

Comment: Qué error recibes?

Comment: No es error del php, es el error que aparece en el "or die("ERROR")" así que no sé cual es el error.

Comment: ¿Que versión de `php` usas? veo que estas usando `mysql` que esta obsoleta en PHP 5.5 y eliminada en PHP 7.0

Comment: uso php 5.4.3 aunque no creo que sea el problema ya que hice otra pagina en la misma base de datos pero otra tabla y si se registran los datos.

Comment: Añade un `try{codigo}catch (Exception $e) {echo $e->getMessage()}` para ver que errores captura

Comment: Para empezar _(no tendría caso ayudar a resolver su problema con la tecnología actual que emplea)_ sería mejor cambiar de extensión `MySQL` está obsoleta, quizá optar por `mysqli` , o `PDO` , es importante que revise esta [pregunta que debe tener en cuenta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)

Comment: como dije no creo que sea usar el mysql porque uso una version de php en la que aun seguia vigente,

Comment: ¿como utilizo el try?
soy nuevo en esto

Comment: Como en el ejemplo que te di pon todo tu codigo en donde esta escrito `codigo`

Comment: me aparece que falta un ;

Comment: Me temo que es problema del campo desc intenta cambiarlo en tu base de datos ya que desc tambien es una palabra reservada de mysql

Comment: esa era la solucion